# Why does rollback occur in spring jpa after first find

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm not sure why rollback occurs after the first find query. The first query perfectly works fine, but rollback constantly occurs if I try to do a query again.

This is the `Controller`.

```java
    //....
    @GetMapping("/s-id/{s-id}")
    public ResponseEntity<DefaultResponseDto<Object>> findManyBySId(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                                                                            @PathVariable(name = "s-id")
                                                                            String sId) {

        // ...
        List<Member> members = memberService.findManyBySpotrightId(spotrightId);
        // ....
    }
    //...
```

This is the `Service`.

```java
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Member> findManyBySId(String spotrightId) {
        try {
            return memberRepository.findBySpotrightIdContainsAndIsDeletedIsFalse(spotrightId);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new CustomException(SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

This is the `Repository`.

```java
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Long> {

    List<Member> findBySIdContainsAndIsDeletedIsFalse(String sId);
}
```

This is the error message that I get in the console

```
2023-02-06 19:21:48.470  INFO 62504 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.s.s.common.aop.TraceAspect             : [START] MemberService | findManyBySpotrightId null | sId = admin  
2023-02-06 19:21:48.473  INFO 62504 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.s.s.common.aop.TraceAspect             : [START] MemberRepository | findBySIdContainsAndIsDeletedIsFalse null
2023-02-06 19:21:48.485  INFO 62504 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] p6spy                                    : #1675678908485 | took 1ms | rollback | connection 8| url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spot?serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8

;
2023-02-06 19:21:48.498 ERROR 62504 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
```

Why does the rollback occur? And How do I fix this problem?

Comment: How do you know a rollback occurs? Does an exception occur? If so what is it's stack trace? The one of the original exception not the `CustomException` which hides all relevant information.

Comment: @jens-schauder yes, I tried not including the `CustomException` and it tells me that an error occurs therefore causing a rollback.

Comment: To quote myself: 
> so what is it's stack trace?

Comment: I've added the error message above. That's the error message without the `CustomException`.

Comment: How do you call your endpoint? Is there by any change a false character (like \) in your uri?

Comment: Nope I don't have any flase character. I fixed the problem by the solution that I wrote down below. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is a bug from Hibernate. I fixed it by including `@Param("sId")` to parameter like below.

```
    List<Member> findBySIdContainingAndIsDeletedIsFalse(@Param("sId") String sId);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).